# What is the difference between a dry cough, wet cough, chesty cough and barking cough?

Tags: terminology, cough

I am doing some research on cough sounds but my background is not health sector and I am facing issues to identify the correct type of cough.

I have two doubts :

1. Is a chesty cough the same as a wet cough?
2. Is a barking cough the same as a dry cough?

If a person is suffering from dry cough is it a barking cough?

Comment: Words like "chesty" are laymen's terms. The medical terms are productive cough (wet) and non-productive cough (dry).

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that wet cough is the same as chesty cough. Dry coughs are those that do not bring up sputum. In my experience, "barking" cough has almost always referred to [croup](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2011/0501/p1067.html).

Comment: But Barking cough is the same as dry cough?

Comment: Because this website https://www.healthgrades.com/right-care/lungs-breathing-and-respiration/barking-cough says A barking cough is a dry, harsh cough that resembles the sound of a barking seal

Comment: So we can assume Barking cough comes under Dry cough? https://www.healthline.com/health/types-of-coughs#dry-cough